# Google Mobile Ads v8 - How do you determine which interstitial ad was dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial, google-mobile-ads

I have recently upgraded to Google Mobile Ads v8. In my App, I have two Interstitial ads in the same ViewController that get displayed at unique interactions. Because of this, I need to be able to determine which Interstitial ad was dismissed in `adDidDismissFullScreenContent` so I can advance the UI accordingly.

Right now I am only determining if it was an Interstitial ad that was dismissed.

```
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    
    if type(of: ad) == GADInterstitialAd.self {
      // Interstitial was dismissed
    }
    
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to determine which ad was dismissed by adUnitID (if that is even possible).

Something like this:

```
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        
    if ad.adUnitID = "Ad1"{
        // Do something.
    } else if ad.adUnitID = "Ad2"{
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

**How can I determine *which* interstitial ad was dismissed using Google Mobile Ads v8?**